# LocalDB Export to Excel

Tags: excel, database-connection, localdb

I have collected a bunch of data using my locally developed website. Now I need to analyze the data, but it seems like I cannot locate the `.mdf` file for the LocalDB database my website uses.

Looking at the data connection, it says `myusername\localdb#abunchofnonsense.mydomainname.Models.UserDBContext.dbo`. And the the connection string is `data source=(localdb)\v11.0; initial catalog=mydomain.models.userdbcontext; integrated security=true`.

Also, I'm using ASP.NET MVC, Visual Studio 2013, and Entity Framework if it helps.

It's probably quite confusing what I'm trying to do here. I collected some data and need to run logistic regression with it. Now the question is how can I connect Excel to this LocalDB so I can export the data I have collected?

Comment: Just use the same connection string. You don't need to know where the file is in order to connect to the database. The files are stored in each user account's AppData folder ([see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx)), which means they are stored in the application pool account's AppData folder. Databases aren't documents and you shouldn't mess with these files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to access it through SQL management studio, but i have no idea what to put as server name to connect. I tried mydomainname/sqlexpress and then it just connect me to the default sql server which doesnt have the database i wanted. I'm having a hard time to find which server that database is sitting on. From what i understand from the connecting string it's on (localbd)\v11.0 but i couldnt find out how to connect to that server. Sorry if it seems dumb, im new to sql database.

Comment: Open the SQL Management Studio and in the "Server name" just put: (LocalDb)\v11.0

Answer (score 4):

You can import your LocalDB tables and data directly into Excel by the option *Get External Data* > *From Other Sources* under the Data tab in Microsoft Excel (2013 to be precise) - as the following screenshot shows:

[image: *Get External Data > From Other Sources in Excel 2013]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I tried, but I bump into a problem that I guess you did not: using either `(localdb)\ProjectsV12` (which works fine in SSMS with Windows authentication) *or* `MYMACHINE\LOCALDB#<Random 8-char Value>` (which is what `select @@SERVERNAME` returns from my LocalDB server) with *Windows Authentication* selected in the Data Connection Wizard's Connect to Database Server screen, **I get the error *[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.***  Maybe this warrants a distinct question, but that what I get when I try this.

Comment: Is your SQL server database a standalone instance or its just a part of your VS project, if it is a part of VS project than you might need to look into msdn documentation, because this excel option connects to a standalone instance. Moreover, if nothing helps, you can always connect to DB via command line and spool the data by querying select * queries to all table.

Comment: As the question tag [localdb] indicates, yes, it is LocalDB (which I happend to install with Visual Studio 2013), not a standalone instance of SQL Server Express, Standard, or Enterprise.  I can connect to it through SSMS without Visual Studio running.

Comment: "...but that [is] what I get when I try this."
.
.
.
"...which I happen[e]d to install with Visual Studio 2013...."

Ugggh, lack of sleep.... :)

Comment: I want to manually award the full 50-point bounty.  Right now this answer would qualify for the 25-point auto bounty award (since it has 2 upvotes) if I cannot justify manually awarding the full bounty; but I am looking for some insight into the failure to connect that I( and therefore others might) encounter when applying this answer (e.g. in an answer edit) to justify manually awarding all 50 points.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but perhaps someone can use the answer as I found this thread when running into a similar problem:

The problem is, that the localdb uses a different provider than the "normal" SQL-Connection. You need to use the "SQL Server Native Client" (in your case version 11) to connect. The provider should be installed with the localdb - if not you can find it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065)

To use in Excel, just choose 
"From Other Sources" 
- "From Data Connection Wizard" 
- "Other Advanced" 
- Choose your provider 
- Enter the rest of your connection details

(not tested, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work): For existing connections you can edit the connection string and add/change "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1" (of course considering your installed version)

Source: I had the same problem in Installshield where you have to change the provider manually, so I just tried in Excel.